# Some doubts regarding Pointers as arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im a beginner at C++ and i want to use dynamic memory allocation technique instead of static (as in array)
for example i want to make 1D array 
int a[100]; 
how should i do the same with pointer ? 
what basically im confused about is that , i have looked over some tutorial on internet and they did it like

```
int a[100];
int *arr = &a[0];
```

i found it quite useless because first we declare array a of size 100, then again we use arr pointer 
can i do it like this

```
int a[1]; 
int *arr= &a[0];
```

now if i do assign random values to arr[i] (from i=0 to i= user defined) 
will it accept it beyond i=1

Comment: C++ gives you lots of rope to hang yourself.

Comment: You can do `int a[1]; a[10] = 5;`. It might work. Or it might crash. Or it might work, but then the next `printf` call might crash. Or it might work, but then suddenly `printf("%d\n", 1+1);` prints 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is C code you're talking about here and these are notoriously annoying to correctly allocate and resize:

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
```

That might come back `NULL` which means you got nothing, so you have to test that it worked out. C++ has the `new` operator which at least throws an exception if it fails, so that makes it harder to ignore:

```
int *arr = new int[100];
```

You should be using C++ Standard Library containers like `std::vector` if you're looking to use C++ effectively:

```
std::vector<int> arr(100);
```

Comment: Thanks :) last but not least can i do int *arr = new int[x]; where x == user defined :D ?

Comment: @KeshavSharma Absolutely, though I hope you'd use a container like `std::vector` instead: `std::vector<int> arr(size)` where `size` is arbitrary value of type `size_t` (`unsigned int` basically).

Comment: Remember whenever you allocate something with `new` you're responsible for a matching `delete` call. Containers are nice in that they often handle this for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

> will it accept it beyond i=1

No, it is UB, since you're trying to access memory you didn't allocate at all.

You might want

```
int* a = new int[user_define_value];
// use it from a[0] ~ a[user_define_value - 1]
delete[] a;
```

BTW: It's a good idea to learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you want to use dynamic size array, and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for static size array in c++.

Answer (score 1):

Re the code snippet

```
int a[1]; 
int *arr= &a[0];
```

… you ask

> **”** if i do assign random values to arr[i] (from i=0 to i= user defined) will it accept it beyond i=1

And the answer is, the code will be accepted (possibly with a warning), but it will then have *Undefined Behavior*, **UB**, because you'll be storing values beyond the end of the allocated array, which is only of size 1.

There is no automatic extension of a raw array.

---

The basic dynamic sized array in C++, is `std::vector`. E.g.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    vector<int> a( 100 );
    // Your code using it, here.
}
```

… does dynamic allocation of the buffer. It also automatically deallocates at the end. And it can dynamically extend itself, e.g. when you use the `push_back` method.

---

With raw pointers you can instead do

```
auto main() -> int
{
    int* a = new int[100];
    // Your code using it, here.
    delete[] a;
}
```

… but this is more brittle code, and it lacks much of the functionality of `std::vector` such as checking the size, appending, assignment and general copying (especially for function result).

And even the basic functionality of the declaration isn't totally equivalent, because with `std::vector` the array items are zero-initialized by default, while the `new`-expression produces an *uninitialized* array, one that has *indeterminate values*. You can however specify that you want zero-initialization, by adding an empty parenthesis. Then it looks like this:

```
int* a = new int[100]();
```

This is just one of the myriad subtleties you have to deal with when you use raw pointers and raw arrays.

As a beginner you should try to avoid raw pointers and raw arrays.

You can't totally avoid them (e.g., `main` takes a raw array argument, any string literal is a raw array, and C style APIs deal with raw arrays), but the more you avoid them, the less problems, and the more productive you are.